# Stop Background Music Playing when Song Download in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

I am downloading song with asihttp request 
My problem is when i click on url to download song, song start playing in my view
How do i stop this, I dont want song should play when downloading 
Please Help

Comment: You're not downloading a song with ASIHTTPRequest, as ASIHTTPRequest has no support at all for playing songs. What are you actually doing? Show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 obj.tagvalue=[sender tag];
NSString * tmp =[NSString stringWithString:[obj.ringArray objectAtIndex:obj.tagvalue]]; 
NSString *filename=[RingUrlArray objectAtIndex:obj.tagvalue];
NSLog(@"%@",filename);


NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:tmp];
NSLog(@"url %@",url);
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];



NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Song"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil]; 

NSString *filePath =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.mp3",dataPath,filename];

NSLog(@"%@",filePath);
[request setDownloadDestinationPath:filePath];
[request  startAsynchronous]; 

UIAlertView *v=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Download Message " message:@"Your download has been started" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[v show];
[v release];
```